# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 + x^{4}}}\ x\ \sin [n\pi\phi(x)] \ }$; $\phi(x)\propto\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+ y^{4}}} $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

Here's the integral:
$$I(n) = \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 + x^{4}}}\ \  x\ \ \sin \lbrack n\pi\phi(x) \rbrack \ }$$
where $n$ is an integer and
$$\phi(x) \equiv \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1 + y^{4}}}\  \ \ \ ;\ \ \ \  \alpha \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1 + y^{4}}} = \frac{\Gamma\left( 1\text{/}4 \right)^{2}}{4\sqrt{\pi}} \ \ . $$
The integral converges because $\ \phi(x\to\infty)\to 1-O(1/x)\ \Rightarrow\ \sin( n\pi \phi )\to O(1/x)$.

 
**Update:** As suggested below by [Claude](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici), one start is to use the hypergeometric series for $\phi(x)$, invert that series using e.g. mathematica to get $x(\phi)$, plug that into the more compact form below, then do the integral. The result is an infinite series over coefficients each of which is a product of a hypergeometric function and a series inverse expansion coefficient, all of which may or may not be tractable, and it's unclear (to me) if that series will converge for large $n$ (which is what is of interest), or how to extract the asymptotic behavior from that series.

Another is the elliptic function pole expansion suggested by [reuns](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986/reuns) below.

So the question is which if any of these is useful for evaluating integrals of the form above, particularly in the large-$n$ limit (or would a steepest descent approach work?). Numerically, the matrix element below, which is the ultimate goal, shows interesting large-$n$ behavior: $B(n,n)\sim \ln{n}$, $\ B(m,n)\sim 1\text{/}|m-n|^{\beta}$, with $1\text{/}2 < \beta < 1 \ $.
$$B(m,n) = \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 + x^{4}}}\ x\ \cos \lbrack (m+1\text{/}2)\pi\phi(x) \rbrack \ \sin \lbrack n\pi\phi(x) \rbrack \ }$$
The goal is to derive that behavior.

Note: The more compact form mentioned above is:
$$I(n) = \int_{- 1}^{1}{d\phi}\ \ x(\phi)\ \sin\lbrack n\pi \phi \rbrack$$
which requires the inverse $x(\phi)$.

Side question: Simplest derivation of the identity for $\alpha$? - see comment by [J.G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/56861/j-g) below.

Comment: You can compute $\alpha_0$ with $u=\frac{1}{1+y^4}$ if you know the Gamma function's reflection formula and how to express the Beta function in terms of the Gamma function.

Comment: [The usual notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) for $\phi(x)$ is $I_{x^4/(1+x^4)}\left(\frac14,\,\frac14\right)$.

Comment: An integration by parts gives $\frac1{\pi n}\int_{-\infty}^\infty ( \cos(\pi n \phi(x))-1)dx$

Comment: @reuns - Agreed. Does that help suggest a useful approach? (Above is the form the integral arises from a WKB approximation to a physical problem)

Comment: In fact your inverse stuff is probably the best approach. $\phi^{-1}$ is an elliptic function, that can be expressed as a series over its poles, from which we can write its Fourier series, which is what you are computing in your $\int_{- 1}^{1}{d\phi}\ \ x(\phi)\ \sin\lbrack n\pi \phi \rbrack$ integral.

Comment: Wait I just realized, $I_n=0$ for all $n$ as $\phi(x)$ is odd so $\sin(\pi n \phi(x))$ is even

Comment: @reuns - Hm - interesting. Can you point me to where to find/learn more about $\phi^{-1}$ and its expansion? Wondering if there is an asymptotic expansion for large n that would be tractable? (Re parity: $\cos(\phi(x))$ would be even; $\sin(\phi(x))$ is odd).

Comment: @reuns. $I_n=0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asymptotics of $I(n)=\int_{-1}^1 x(\phi)\sin n\pi\phi\,d\phi$ depends on the behavior of $x(\phi)$ at $\phi\to\pm1$ (simple poles, considering $x(\phi)$ analytically continued). Observe that $\phi(x)+\phi(1/x)=1$, hence $x(\phi)x(1-\phi)=1$. Thus the residues of $x(\phi)$ at $\phi\in\{\pm1\}$ are equal to $-1/\alpha$, as well as of $$y(\phi)=\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}\tan\frac{\pi\phi}{2},$$ so that $x(\phi)-y(\phi)$ is regular at $\phi\in\{\pm1\}$. This gives, as $n\to\infty$, $$I(n)\asymp\int_{-1}^1 y(\phi)\sin n\pi\phi\,d\phi=\frac\pi\alpha(-1)^{n-1}.$$

The behavior of $B(m,n)$ may be analysed similarly, using $$\frac\pi2\int_{-1}^1\tan\frac{\pi\phi}{2}\,\cos\left(m+\frac12\right)\pi\phi\,\sin n\pi\phi\,d\phi=(-1)^{m+n-1}(S_{m,n}+S_{m,n-1}),\\S_{m,n}=\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac1{2m+2k+1}.$$

---

**UPDATE.** Diving into elliptic functions, one gets an *exact* formula $$x(\phi)=\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}\left(\tan\frac{\pi\phi}{2}+4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin n\pi\phi}{e^{n\pi}+(-1)^n}\right)$$ *(should I elaborate this?)* and thus an exact formula for $I(n)$.

Comment: Nice!!! Well done. Thanks a million :) What a great site.

Answer (score 1):

Using the gaussian hypergeometric function
$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1 + y^{4}}}=x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{4};-x^4\right)$$
$$\phi(x)=\frac{4}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k  \frac{ \Gamma \left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)}{(4 k+1)\, k!}x^{4 k+1}$$ Truncating to $O\left(x^{29}\right)$ (just to give a maximum of terms fitting on one line), by series inversion
$$x=t+\frac{t^5}{10}+\frac{t^9}{120}+\frac{11 t^{13}}{15600}+\frac{211
   t^{17}}{3536000}+\frac{1607 t^{21}}{318240000}+\frac{1511
   t^{25}}{3536000000}+O\left(t^{29}\right)$$ where $$t=\frac{4 }{\sqrt{\pi }} \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2\phi $$

Comment: Thanks. I agree the series is correct, but see above under update - how does one extract large-n (or any n) behavior?